# Community Promotion ad on Raspberry Pi SE

Tags: discussion

Greetings which I hope make it past the remove greetings bot ;)   Yes, this is much the same post as the one I just put up at IoT.SE Meta, almost.

I added the Arduino.SE community promotion ad used in years past at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ to the new [(2019) selection page there](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/community-promotion-ads-2019); they must be renewed annually.

That one is totally fine, but if anyone thinks they have a better one, post it here and I will replace it (rather than having competing ads for the same site).  *Be sure you understand the requirements for the image first*, they are in the question on the RPi Meta page linked above.

Also, if you are a voting member at RPi.SE, please upvote the ad, since they must reach a threshold in order to appear. The specific "answer" [is here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2136/5538).

Comment: The Arduino promotion ad should be posted on the Arduino Meta page - not the Raspberry Pi page. https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2561/19409

Comment: No.  What's the point of promoting a site on its own page?  There's already a banner at the top.  Anyway, it is totally normative practice to do both (promote the local exchange as well as related ones).  In fact, it's totally normal to promote non-SE sites if enough people vote the ad as appropriate.  E.g., Rpi has usually had a link to the foundation's github page, on U&L you'll find community ads for various linux distros, etc.  The SO version is even explicitly about ads for open source software: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379273/open-source-advertising-1h-2019

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.